# Question: Does this sequence converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does this sequence converge?  $$\sqrt[n]{2^{1+3n}} $$

I decided to switch it up and try to take the $ln$ of it to make the equation now:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n{2^{1+3n}} $$

and this is where I lose it. I tried separating the powers of 2 and moving the 2 over to the left of the limit. But I don't know where to go from here, or if this is the way to approach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite this as $2^{\frac{1+3n}{n}}$

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\sqrt[n]{2^{1+3n}}\sim_\infty \sqrt[n]{2^{3n}}=2^3=8$$

Answer (score 0):

You have made a error in your logarithm.

In fact $\ln\left(\sqrt[n]{2^{1+3n}}\right)= \frac1n (1+3n) \ln(2)$ and it should be now be obvious whether it converges.